# Query has no destination for result data in custom function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to postgres and I'm trying to populate some table with result from select statement. But I get this error:

```
[42601] ERROR: query has no destination for result data
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Where: PL/pgSQL function get_child_folder_mask(integer) line 12 at SQL statement
```

Here's the query I use:

```
insert into public."security_report_data" ("ReportID", "SDID", "PermissionType", "Mask")
    select val_ReportID, tMain."SDID", t1."PermissionType", public."get_child_folder_mask"(t1."Mask") <----
    from    public."table_{00000000-eeea-4e2e-a04c-d4351282fb55}" tMain
            inner join public."table_{00000000-eeea-4e2e-a04c-d4351282fb55}" tParent
                on tMain."ParentTreeRowID" = tParent."RowID"
            inner join public."report_aces" t1
                on tParent."SDID" = t1."SDID"
            inner join public."report_accounts" t2
                on t1."Account" = t2."Account"
                and (t2."Member" = val_Account or public."fn_is_everyone"(t2."Member") = true);
```

get_child_folder_mask's code:

```
create function get_child_folder_mask(val_parentfoldermask integer DEFAULT NULL::integer) returns integer
    language plpgsql
as
$$
declare val_Mask integer = 0;
begin   

    if ((val_ParentFolderMask & x'00000004'::integer) = x'00000004'::integer) then
        select val_Mask = val_Mask | x'00000002'::integer;
    end if;

    if ((val_ParentFolderMask & x'00000008'::integer) = x'00000008'::integer) then
        select val_Mask = val_Mask | x'00010000'::integer;
    end if;

    return val_Mask;
end;
$$;
```

I found out that if change get_child_folder_mask's argument from t1."Mask" to some constant integer value error will disappear. I will be glad for any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a SELECT to [assign](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-ASSIGNMENT) a variable value in PL/pgSQL:

```
if ((val_ParentFolderMask & x'00000004'::integer) = x'00000004'::integer) then
    val_Mask := val_Mask | x'00000002'::integer;
end if;

if ((val_ParentFolderMask & x'00000008'::integer) = x'00000008'::integer) then
    val_Mask := val_Mask | x'00010000'::integer;
end if;
```